# Multiple Eclipse Mars Installations Ubuntu 15

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, launcher

I am setting up my development environment after an Ubuntu reinstall. It looks like Eclipse has multiple versions of installers (Java, CPP, PHP, etc) for different languages.

Suppose I install all of them into the following directories. Each directory has a corresponding Eclipse executable in it.

> ~/eclipse/cpp-mars/eclipse/
>   ~/eclipse/jee-mars/eclipse/
>   ~/eclipse/php-mars/eclipse/
>   ~/eclipse/java-mars/eclipse/

My first question is whether the above programs are truly standalone programs. That is, can I add them separately to Unity Launcher? Or do they run behind the scenes on the same platform and require only one icon?

Next question relates to adding the icons into the launcher. I created the following file but it did not do the trick. What is the optimal way of getting all of the icons into Launcher?

```
/usr/share/applications/eclipse-java.desktop:

[Desktop Entry]
Name=Eclipse-Java
Type=Application
Exec=/home/userman/eclipse/java-mars/eclipse
Terminal=false
Icon=/home/userman/eclipse/java-mars/eclipse/icon.xpm
Comment=Integrated Development Environment for JAVA
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Development;IDE;
Name[en]=Eclipse
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.22
```

Comment: You can add all of the other languages to one install through eclipse update, what do you ultimately **want**?

Comment: I do not care to have them separately. I just want the ability to use the functions. How do I do that?

Comment: Start eclipse. "Help" > "Install New Software", select "All Available Sites", and then you'll be able to install the C++, PHP, etc tools. As for the launcher, you'll probably have better luck on [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) (the Ubuntu Stack).

Comment: I see. I mean, which version of installer should choose for that?

Comment: Any. eclipse is *very* [modular](https://www.osgi.org/). For example, per the Spring Tool Suite (STS) [download](https://spring.io/tools/sts/all) instructions; *If you want to install STS in an existing Eclipse installation, you can use one of the following update sites.* And it then lists a site for 4.4 and a site for 4.5, if you add that to the "Available Software Sites" preferences (top right of the window during "Help" > "Install New Software") you can add one url and then add in STS. Or whatever else you want...